# how to share data from buyer to seller where they share the same app?

Tags: android

I have an idea in my mind to build an app that has users download the app and request for the order quantity of products needed and I wish to receive the information via the same app.I don't have many parameters to send from user to me, it is only the order quantity.

I am stuck at how to pass the quantity form user to me. Is using a Server the option or are there any other options? If so are there any free servers that are available? In this process, which protocol is the best to communicate?

Please suggest ideas.

Comment: have you tried anything? what did not worked?

Comment: I am not aware of how to do it. Do we need to have a server for it? Or are there any other means to do?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have found how to work this out. We need to have a server and its mandatory (to pass some set of data) and use HTTP protocols to communicate.